# How to use Cglib to update fields of a class in runtime by reading a XML configuration?

Tags: java, cglib

Considering the commonality and flexibility of our project, we need to add fields and related get/set methods into a basic class with a array of columns from a `XML` configuration file. I was thinking of Cglib and did a study about it.

I've learned that how to use Cglib to implement AOP functionality in application like this:

```
public static SampleManager getSelectivityAuthInstance(AuthProxy auth) {
  Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
  enhancer.setSuperclass(SampleManager .class);
  enhancer.setCallbacks(new Callback[] { auth, NoOp.INSTANCE });
  enhancer.setCallbackFilter(new AuthProxyFilter());

  return (SampleManager ) enhancer.create();
}
```

There is insufficient resources for learning and researching Cglib on the internet. I was wishing to get a help from here. Following is my question in detail.

1, I have a basic POJO class `BasicUser` which is empty primitively.

2, Application should have ability to read a list of fields that includes information like name, data type, length,etc from `project.xml`, and add these fields in the BasicUser class, and then application uses the new class updated by `Cglib` to reach business requirements.

I ever thought to use Map to implement it, but it's not technical. Can anybody professional gives me guidance.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a class for this in cglib, the `BeanGenerator`. I wrote something about the use of this class here: http://mydailyjava.blogspot.no/2013/11/cglib-missing-manual.html